# Can I answer differently if get different slot value in same intent, AWS Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

**What I am trying to achieve:**
I am trying to answer differently if a get differently value for the same slot

**Example:**
I have made an intent with a slot having months of the year.
so when user says specific month i.e. March then i want to tell all the events happened in the March only.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried making an intent with a slot and on the back end i am able to get the name the month that slot got filled with.

**Please help!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slot can carry a number of values. Amazon even has a predefined month slot type.

Here's part of an Alexa beginner tutorial that asks for your birthday. It should help you understand this.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill/module-4

**Updating**

If you're needing to understand how to return different responses based on the slot value, your best bet would be to learn how to use a `switch` statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch